# Encoding and decoding two integer values both 0-3 into one byte

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to encode two values a "movement direction" which can be 0,1,2, or 3 and a "looking direction" which can also be 0, 1, 2, or 3

I know it's possible to store this information into one byte

So I'm a still kind of novice at bitwise operations so trying to figure this out has stumped me.

I want to be have a function like

```
function encode(m, l) {
   // returns byte
}

function decode(byte) {
    // returns { m, l }
}
```

Comment: How many values do you need to pack into a single byte?  You need 2 bits to store values from 0 to 3 in binary form.

Comment: Oh right.. so I guess i don't even need a whole byte for this. I only need 4 bits then. I only want to store those two numbers m and l into the bits

Comment: So, what seems to be a problem?  If you want two values in a byte, assign them different bits and in order to retrieve one of them have `and` with 1s where you number is and 0s in all other places.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, Javascript does not have a byte data type.  It only has the number type.  There is no requirement for Javascript to store your result in a single byte even if it fits in one.

You need 2 bits to store a number 0, 1, 2, or 3.
Two more bits to store the other 0,1,2,3.  The second number needs to be bit shifted over by 2 bits and added to the first.  This is the same as multiplying by 4.  So...

```
function encode(m,l) {
    return m + l * 4;
}

function decode(byte) {
  var m = byte % 4;
  var l = (byte - m ) /4;
  return {m:m, l:l};
}
```

It might be faster to do this with a lookup.

```
 (0,0) <=> 0
 (1,0) <=> 1
 (2,0) <=> 2
 (3,0) <=> 3
 (0,1) <=> 4
 (1,1) <=> 5
 (2,1) <=> 6
 (3,1) <=> 7
 (0,2) <=> 8
 (1,2) <=> 9
 (2,2) <=> 10
 (3,2) <=> 11
 (0,3) <=> 12
 (1,3) <=> 13
 (2,3) <=> 14
 (3,3) <=> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map a byte to assign the left four bits to the movement and the right for to the looking direction, then shift a bit along to set it. Decoding uses a right shift and takes the log base 2 to see which bit was set.

```js
const encode = (movement, lookDir) =>
  // mmmmllll
  (1 << (movement + 4)) | (1 << lookDir)
;

const decode = byte =>
  [Math.log2(byte >> 4), Math.log2(byte & 0xF)]
;

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    const encoded = encode(i, j);
    const decoded = decode(encoded);
    console.log(`[${i},${j}] was encoded as: ${encoded} and decoded back to ${decoded}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to encode two values a "movement direction" which can be 0,1,2, or 3 and a "looking direction" which can also be 0, 1, 2, or 3

The generalization of this is a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). If you count your range in binary it becomes more intuitive how you can combine your values:

```js
(0).toString(2).padStart(8, 0); // = 00000000
(1).toString(2).padStart(8, 0); // = 00000001
(2).toString(2).padStart(8, 0); // = 00000010
(3).toString(2).padStart(8, 0); // = 00000011
```

Your range uses the two lower bits, so to encode these the bitwise way, all you need to do is SHIFT one of your values into the adjacent two bits on the left and OR the two values together. i.e first variable uses bits 0,1 and second variable uses bits 2,3.

```js
const encodeC = (a, b) => (a << 2) | b;
```

To decode `a` we simply reverse the shift on `c`, nothing more is needed since `b` gets pushed off the end of the right hand side of the "word":

```js
const decodeA = (c) => c >> 2;
```

To decode `b` we need to "mask" it from `c` in order to select the two lower bits and exclude all others, we do this with an AND (`&`) of `0b11` (3):

```js
const decodeB = (c) => c & 3;
```

Note that in the example above, `b` must be guaranteed to be in the range 0-3 otherwise it will overflow into the bits reserved for `a`. `a` on the other hand has another 28 free bits to it's left, so it could go much higher.

As others have mentioned, in terms of memory allocation all numbers in JavaScript use 64bits (doubles), which are temporarily cast to 32bit signed ints when performing bitwise operations. This means you can never use less memory for a single variable and can only utilise up to half the bits (32) for bitfields.

This does not make use of bitfields invalid in JavaScript though, more so if for example you are going to do further encoding into a character or something for sending over AJAX. You could use `c.toString(36)` (0-36) or `String.charFromCode(c + 32)` (0-95). For your use of 4 bits you only need a range of 0-15.

... If you encode into ASCII chars it really will be using one byte :)